# Measure preserving system and a integer subset

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, ergodic-theory

I want to show that :

> Fix a measurable preserving system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$.
>
> Let $E\subset \mathbb{N}$ be such that
>   $$lim\sup_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|E\cap\left\{1,2,\cdots,N\right\}|}{N}=1.$$ Then for any $A\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(A)>0$, there is a
>   $n\in E$ such that $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)>0$.

I already know that ***Poincare recurrence theorem :***

> Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be a measurable preserving system.
>   For any $A\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(A)>0$, there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>    such that $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)>0$.

So what I have to do is to find $n$ in the $E$.
The assumption on $E$ looks nice. It means almost every elements in $\left\{1,2,\cdots,N\right\}$ are in $E$.

Comment: You can show that the set $\{n:\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)>0\}$ is of positive lower density. And any set of positive lower density and any set of upper density 1 have nonempty intersection.

Comment: @SimingTu Wow... Thanks so much. I really appreciate that. Genius.

Comment: @SimingTu Can you give me a hint for the first statement? I proved second one. How can I find ${n:μ(A∩T−nA)>0}$ has a positive loer density?

Comment: Hint: Try to apply mean ergodic theorem.

Comment: @SimingTu $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu\left(A\cap T^{-n}A\right)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int\chi_{A}T^{n}\chi_{A}\ dx=\int_{A}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}T^{n}\chi_{A}\ dx\longrightarrow\int_{A}P\chi_{A}\ dx$
where $P$ is a projection map into $T$-invariant space and $\chi$ is an indicator function.

Since $\int_{A}P\chi_{A}\ dx>0$(why?) $\{n\ :\ \mu\left(A\cap T^{-n}A\right)>0\}$
has positive lower density(why?). Is this correct?